# Forcing the return value of a function to be stored in a const variable/to be treated as const

Tags: c++

A similar, maybe the same, question has been asked here:
[force const storing of returned by value value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522449/force-const-storing-of-returned-by-value-value)

However, much of the discussion was focused on "Why would you do that?"

Let's say I have struct A and B that both contain a shared_pointer.
Now I have class C. Class C contains an instance of A.
C has a const method getB() that return an object of type B, created on the moment and that contains a copy of the shared_pointer of A. However, I would like that whoever called getB() could not modify the content of B, especially the area of memory pointed by the shared_pointer.

In my user case, I am not in the position to modify class A and class B (which happen to be IplImage and cv::Mat of Opencv)

Is the only way to obtain my target to return a newly created `B const *`? (In this respect, [this is a very useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const/1143272#1143272))

Comment: I'm not a C++ guru, but it seems that what you want is a frozen object, not a const pointer...

Comment: @fortran What he seems to want doesn't make sense.  C++ uses value semantics, so you can always copy the returned value to a non-const variable, and modify that.

Comment: Why can't you return a const reference?

Comment: @Mikhail: Because it can be copied.

Comment: @Mikhail Because I would like class C not to contain an instance of class B. What getB() has to return depends on the current value of the instance of A belonging to C. If my class had 2 members `A m_a;` and `B m_b`, I would have to maintain m_b to be changed at each change of m_a. Updating m_b when getB() is called would make my method not const anymore.

Comment: @Andrew What does "return an object of type B, created on the moment" mean? If the new `B` object is created, who's gonna delete it?

Comment: @Mikhail a copy is returned. `Foo someMethod() {return Foo();}`

Comment: @Mikhail To guarantee deletion, I can return a `boost::shared_ptr<const B>`. This shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `proxy` pattern: http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html

Create a proxy of `B` that will control access to it and return a proxy instead of `B` itself from your method.

```
class BProxy
{
public:
    BProxy(const B &b) : _b(b) {}

    void doSomeStuff() {...}    

private:
    B _b;
};
```